# swipe navigation in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, swipe, viewcontroller

I want to add a second view controller to my project with a swipe navigation. Which is the easiest way?

As you can see in the picture I have these buttons in the first view, I want to add more. I also have a background picture which is not in the picture
(below), is it possible to keep it for both views? So when I swipe to the right the background should't move, only the buttons. 
Also could you please explain to me how I should make it step by step, because I am new into coding and have almost no experience.
[image]

Comment: Use UIPageViewController if both views have major UI changes. Otherwise use scrollView pagination

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to find is paging using UIScrollView. Check out this [link](http://sweettutos.com/2015/04/13/how-to-make-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-storyboards-swift/).

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the custom class called ADPageControl. Here is the reference link : **https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/adcustompagecontrol**.

And for that image you can set the common image below your container view. Please go through the link and try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a `UIPageViewController` But you have tweak a little bit. You can find a tutorial about that [here](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-tutorial-using-uipageviewcontroller-create-content-slider-objective-cswift/)

Few Points

- Create PageViewController with buttons
- Make each Page views background color as clear color so your background image will be shown all the time even when you swipe.
- Please don't expect full code from SO

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying implement something like ..look below code

> its scrollview paging

```
// viewArray contains paging views  
viewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.viewOne, self.viewTwo, nil];

// adding all views as scrollview subview 
for (int i = 0; i < viewArray.count; i++) {
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:viewArray[i]];
}

// this time you need to set scrollview contentSize but in X axis .. 
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * viewArray.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

**have a note**: you can create views using storyboard or programmatically but must set the x position of views which you want to appear on swipe.. hope this helps.